# How to display logs when running a dotnet core app in Rider?

Tags: logging, .net-core, rider

So I have switched from Visual Studio to Rider, and so far it's been nothing but amazing.

The only thing I'm missing is the logging output. The solution consists of 4 projects and when I launched them all in Visual Studio 2017 I got the logs in the Output window.

With Rider I can set the IIS Express output in the launch config but, it's not giving me any actual dotnet core logging, just requests/status code.

Note that I am not debugging rather just running the application.

I am using the default `WebHostBuilder` for all my projects.

```
private static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
   WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
     .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

The only hunch I get is that my app which is using the `VueCliMiddleware` ([repo](https://github.com/EEParker/aspnetcore-vueclimiddleware)) outputs the logs from it's build process, going as far is giving me linting error.

This is telling me I need to take an extra step to display the default `aspnetcore` logs, anyone might know what config I might be missing?

Comment: @bitbonk could you give it a go with launching more than 1 project together?

Comment: Yes that works too: https://i.postimg.cc/vBt0Cj4T/Untitled.png

Comment: @bitbonk can't find my Run window, probably missin something simple, If I press Alt + 4 it doesn't show up. Instead I ahve Services window. But creating 2 fresh projects have logging no problem.

Comment: The services window has a tab that says „console“. I would guess that’s where the log output would go to. If you want to get the run window back you could try to delete the .idea folder in your solution folder. This will reset Rider to your defaults.

Comment: @bitbonk I was thinking of doing that, I have tried to far to delete all profiles and create a `.NET Project` template and it brings up the Run window and showed logs. Compared to `.NET Launch Settings Profile` not sure what the difference is other than Kester/IIS Express. And I can't find the "console" tab, I do have a window where the output is meant to go but I just get a `Waiting for the IIS Express worker process to start…`

Comment: @bitbonk deleting `.idea` folder didn't help the logging situation. I guess the fault is at a project level, it did bring back the Run window tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** check your `web.config`

This was entirely my bad. The fault was in the web.config present in my projects because I used to run them throught actual IIS when under VS2017 and not IIS Express, for my services to be accessed on local network. This is what was generated:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="bin\IISSupport\VSIISExeLauncher.exe" arguments="-argFile IISExeLauncherArgs.txt" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" stdoutLogEnabled="false" startupTimeLimit="3600" requestTimeout="00:10:00">
  <environmentVariables>
    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
  </environmentVariables>
</aspNetCore>
```

Most likely `stdoutLogEnabled="false"` is the main culprit of the logs not showing.

I replaced the above with and all is good (deleting it work's too I kept it because I need to tell IIS what the maximum file upload size is, if you are using Kestrel delete it.):

```
<aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%">
</aspNetCore>
```